# How to add external SQL Server database to an ASP.NET MVC application (c#)

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I want to add external SQL Server database to my ASP.NET MVC application (C#). 
For the project for which I am working, I have to use external SQL Server database instead of using built-in local database.

Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either add Entity Framework to your solution or look up how to work with System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand. You'll likely end up using both as both have it's advantages.

Answer (score 0):

In your project/solution add an ADO.Net Entity Model.